# traefik not redirecting to https

Tags: docker, container, letsencrypt

I'm trying to set up a home automation server, with docker, letsencrypt and traefik. Also using duckdns for ddns. I have some other containers like sickrage and so on on the same machine.

I've opened and forwarded ports 80 and 443 on the router to my ubuntu 18.04 server. When I try to connect to sickrage.myserver.duckdns.org on http I get the following error:

```
**Your connection is not private**
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from sabnzbd.myserver.duckdns.org 
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Here is my traefik.toml file:

```
    logLevel = "WARN" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

# WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend and backend configurations 
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  address = ":8080"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
     entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]


[file]
  watch = true
  filename = "${USERDIR}/docker/traefik/rules.toml"

# Let's encrypt configura
[acme]
caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
email = "mr.akita@gmail.com"     #any email id will work
storage="${USERDIR}/docker/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true 
onDemand = false #create certificate when container is created
onHostRule = true
  # Use a HTTP-01 acme challenge rather than TLS-SNI-01 challenge
  # uncomment 2 lines for subdirs
#[acme.httpChallenge]
[acme.dnsChallenge]
provider = "duckdns"
entryPoint = "https"
  # uncomment follwoing for suubsomains
#[[acme.domains]]
  #main = "myserver.duckdns.org"
#[[acme.domains]]
  #main = "*.myserver.duckdns.org"
#[acme.dnsChallenge]
  #provider = "duckdns"
  #delayBeforeCheck = 0

# Connection to docker host system (docker.sock)
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "myserver.duckdns.org"
watch = true
# This will hide all docker containers that don't have explicitly  
# set label to "enable"
exposedbydefault = false
```

And parts of my docker-compose file:

```
    ---
version: "3.6"
services:
  #############################################   Frontends               ############################
  #############################################   Traefik - Reverse proxy  ###########################
  traefik:
    hostname: traefik
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    domainname: ${DOMAINNAME} 
    command: --api --docker --docker.domain=${DOMAINNAME} --docker.watch --loglevel=DEBUG
    #command: --api --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --docker.watch --loglevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - default
      - traefik_proxy
    depends_on:
      - duckdns
    environment:
      - TOKEN=${DUCKDNS_TOKEN}
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8008:8080"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
        #- "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=patrick:$$2y$$05$$a8dtYfcMqH.kUFq3zZPGqe9kq7Tyok7.3/mKdMa1NaCuSwAZ0InOq"
        #- "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /traefik"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${DOMAINNAME}"  
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=315360000"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost=dellubuntu.duckdns.org"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=false"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.frameDeny=true"
        #- "traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=${HTTP_USERNAME}:${HTTP_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik/acme/acme.json:/acme.json
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt:/le-ssl
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
  #Letsencrypt                                                    ------------------------ Letsencrypt
  letsencrypt:
    image:  linuxserver/letsencrypt
    container_name: le
    #ports:
      #- "447:443"
    networks:
      - default
      - traefik_proxy
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/letsencrypt/config:/config
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - portainer
      - heimdall
      - organizr2
      - lazylibrarian
      - plex
      - tautulli
      - headphones
        #- lidarr
      - couchpotato
        #- radarr
      - sickrage
        #- sonarr
        #- airsonic
      - glances
      - ghost
      - transmission-vpn
      - sabnzbd
      - huginn
      - netdata
        #- nextcloud
        #- hydra2
        #- nzbget
        #- jackett
        ##- duplicati
        ##- bazarr
        ##- homeassistant
        ##- filebrowser
        ##- ombi
        ##- elkarbackup
    environment:
      - PUID=${PUID}
      - PGID=${PGID}
      - TZ=${TZ}
      - URL=${DOMAINNAME}
      - EMAIL=${EMAIL}
      - SUBDOMAINS=wildcard
      - VALIDATION=duckdns
      - DUCKDNSTOKEN=${DUCKDNS_TOKEN}
      - ONLY_SUBDOMAINS=false
      - DHLEVEL=4096
```

The examples I've tried to follow doesn't include the letsencrypt container. Should I remove it? If so, how will letsencrypt keep track of stopped and started containers? Is there another way to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traefik includes letsencrypt integration, it's not necessary to a separate letsencrypt container.

Traefik also terminates TLS connections by default, passing requests to your application in HTTP over the docker internal networking. Your connection will still be secure over the internet, but the application you are connecting to will not know that. You can reencrypt the connection by specifying `traefik.protocol=https` on your service, but then your application will need to maintain its own TLS certificates that Traefik needs to be configured to trust, since these will not come from LetsEncrypt.